# Do not change right the icon,java

Tags: java, image, icons

i have a problem with my code. I think that my problem is easy,but i have compiled for 3 days without good results. I have three images. They are put on screen one-one each time. User choose from 4 button if image's side is up, down, right or left. Also, i want to understand if user was wrong and then i will count errors. When user make 3 errors then the game will stop. I have shown code below. Please help me if you have any good idea. 
The problem is that at the first loop,run right.It goes at the first if. After that it do the loop and then it does not go to second if. 
if it is more helpful,some details:
i want to make a programma that it will show to user an image.This image has 4 sides (up,down,right,left).When the image is at "up side",user has to click on up button,when the image is at "down side",user has to click on down button etc. User can do 3 errors max. At first,program show the image at right side,if user clicks on right button then i want to show the "second image" at left side.If user does not at left side,then i want to add an error(error++) and after it shows the third image at up side etc. I hope it is more helpful to understand. If you can't please let me know.
My program is at Netbeans,java.
Thank you

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{    
    while(errors<3)
    {
        image.setIcon(createImageIcon("visual1" + e.getActionCommand() + ".PNG"));
        if (k==1) 
        {
            if(e.getSource() == right_button)
            {
                image.setIcon(createImageIcon("visual2" + e.getActionCommand() + ".PNG"));          
            }          
        } 
        else if ( k==2 )
        {
            if(e.getSource() == left_button )
            {
                image.setIcon(createImageIcon("visual3" + e.getActionCommand() + ".PNG"));
            }
        }       
        else if (k==3 )
        {
            if(e.getSource() == up_button)
            {
                System.out.print("if3");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            errors++;
        }
        k=k+1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't speak for all, but I am having a hard time understanding your problem and your code. I think that part of it might be a language issue. Please consider telling and showing us more.

Comment: Your code likes like it might go into a long running or never-stopping while loop that will block the Swing event thread, freezing your program. Is this what is happening?

Comment: If it doesn't go to the second if, then it may be that k doesn't = 2, so why not put a print statement in to print the values of k at the start of the while loop to check that k = 2 is one of them, or have you already done this?

Comment: I think this is what he's trying to say - 

The user is shown 3 images. The user has to answer if the image's orientation is up(the correct orientation) or down(reverse) or right or left. The user can make at most 3 mistakes. 

@user2933161 can you confirm ?

Comment: Sorry.So,i want to make a programma that it will show to user an image.This image has 4 sides (up,down,right,left).When the image is at "up side",user has to click on up button,when the image is at "down side",user has to click on down button etc. User can do 3 errors max. At first,program show the image at right side,if user clicks on right button then i want to show the "second image" at left side.If user does not at left side,then i want to add an error(error++) and after it shows the third image at up side etc. I hope it is more helpful to understand. If you can't please let me know.

Comment: You will want to edit your question and add the text above to it. Also, what happens when the user presses a button? Does the program freeze up? Does it blow up?

Comment: @bluesh34 i have already try to put a print statement,and the k takes tha values 1,2,3 etc.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels when the users presses the button at first time,i changes icon as we want.But after that the programm freeze up.

Comment: @AnkitRustagi Thank you. I mean exactly what you say ! Sorry if my english is not so good.

Comment: And have you put a print statement in the if(k==2) and if(k==3) to print what e.getSource is? If so, does anything get printed, and if so, what?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider calling [Repaint](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html) and [Invalidate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#invalidate%28%29), right after you update your GUI like this -

```
    mainframe.repaint();
    mainframe.invalidate();
```

here mainframe is your JFrame object.

Comment: This is not what he needs, and should never be needed when setting a JLabel's Icon.

Comment: Thanks @HovercraftFullOfEels , have anyone any good idea? I think that it is easy,however i try it 3 days.. :/

Answer (score 0):

A problem I see with your while loop is that it is at risk of getting stuck in an infinite loop, since the variable used as an exit criterion is only updated some of the time, in an else block. I think you should re-arrange your logic:

- Get rid of that while loop as it will only cause trouble. It is useful for a linear command line program but not for an event-driven GUI program like yours.
- Read in all images and create all ImageIcons in the class constructor, and store them in variables. There's no need to re-read the images multiple times (unless they're huge).
- Instead of using a while loop, increment the error variable in your method above, and then write the method so that it will change behaviors depending on the value of error (depending on the *state* of the class).

e.g.,

```
// somewhere in your code create your icons
Icon rightIcon = ......;
Icon leftIcon = .....;
Icon upIcon = .....;
Icon downIcon = .....;

// elsewhere in your code
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  if (errors >= 3) {
    // notify user of error
    return;  // end this method
  }

  // check if current icon matches image
  // if so, change icon
  // if not increment error
}
```

Note that an `enum Direction {UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT}` and a `Map<Direction, Icon>` could be helpful here.

Comment: Thans for your help,i try this way. I hope,it is helpful for me ! :)